# What Makes Chunks Eligible for Spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to the wiki,

```
mobCap = constant * chunks / 289
```

It's obvious I'm not going to be changing the constant, or the `/ 289` part, so how can I change the variable `chunks`? Well, to answer that question, I first have to know: what an eligible chunk? Is it a chunk in the 17*17 area around the player, or is there a more specific criteria?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it's just 17*17, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's the 17x17 around *all* players. This doesn't matter if you playing solo, but can be quite a drag if you're playing multiplayer and everyone has a mob farm!